# Why doesn't this program overflow?

Tags: c#, integer-overflow

Trying to study how C# reacts to overflows, I wrote this simple code :

```
static uint diff(int a, int b)
{
    return (uint)(b - a);
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(int.MaxValue);
    uint l = diff(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(l);
    Console.In.ReadLine();
}
```

I get this output :

```
2147483647
4294967295
```

I find surprising that it ran so well, as the int subtraction in `diff` should give a result greater than `int.MaxValue`.

However, if I write this, which seems to be equivalent to the above code :

```
uint l = (uint)(int.MaxValue - int.MinValue);
```

C# won't even compile, because the code could overflow.

What makes the first code run without overflow, while the compiler won't even compile the second line ?

Comment: One of your scenarios is a compile-time constant, the other one isn't. The compiler can prevent the former so it does.

Comment: Read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked At compile-time you are in checked mode, at runtime you are in unchecked mode.

Comment: I think the first case does actually overflow and then the cast takes a value which has overflown (and is probably now negative) and casts it as unsigned which in turn underflows and the value becomes the max uint

Comment: If you ran it in debug, you'd get an OverflowException.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use constant values:

```
uint l = (uint)(int.MaxValue - int.MinValue);
```

The compiler knows exactly what you're trying to do because it knows the values, and it sees that the result of the subtraction cannot fit in an `int`, so it gives you the error.

When you use variables:

```
return (uint)(b - a);
```

The compiler has no idea at compile time what the values of the variables will be, so it doesn't complain.

Note that the overflow is in the `int`, not `uint` as you stated in your now-deleted answer. You may think that you are subtracting big value from small value, but you're not. The `int.MinValue` is actually negative (-2147483648) and subtracting it means you're actually adding it (2147483647 - (-2147483648)), so the result (4294967295) cannot fit in `int`, but it can fit in `uint`. So for example, this will compile and give the correct result 4294967295:

```
uint x = (uint)((long)int.MaxValue - int.MinValue);
```

Because now you're telling the compiler to store the result of the subtraction in `long` instead of `int` and that will work. Now print `x` to the console and notice that the result of the subtraction is 4294967295, not -1 as you're stating in your answer. If it was -1 like you said, then the code below should compile, but it doesn't because 4294967295 overflows the `int`:

```
int x = int.MaxValue - int.MinValue;
```

**Edit** There are more people who are struggling to understand the result, so here is even more explanation that I hope will help:

First of all, we all know that `int.MaxValue` is 2147483647 and `int.MinValue` is -2147483648. I hope that we also all agree on this simple math without having to prove it in a program:

```
2147483647 - (-2147483648) = 4294967295
```

So we should all agree that the math result is 4294967295, not -1. If somebody does not agree with that, please go back to school.

So why the result in the program is sometimes -1 which is confusing so many people?

OK, we all agree that an overflow occurs, so that's not the issue. Some people don't understand where the overflow is happening. It is not happening when casting to `uint`. Surely -1 will overflow `uint`, but the program is overflowing the `int` in the step before casting to `uint`. When an overflow occurs, the program behavior varies depending the on the execution context (checked or unchecked). In a checked context, an `OverflowException` is thrown, and nothing is executed afterwards, so the casting to `uint` is not executed. In an unchecked context, the most significant bits of the result are discarded and execution continues, so the casting to `uint` is then executed and another overflow occurs. Here is [an MSDN article about how the integer overflows behave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index#arithmetic-overflow).

So let's see how we're getting -1:

First, in C#, when you subtract two integers, the result is an integer. Now if the result cannot fit in an integer, an overflow occurs. The tricky part is that in an unchecked context, the most significant bits of the result are discarded, like I mentioned above. In the question's scenario, that results in -1. Here are some examples that I hope will make this clear:

```
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(int.MaxValue)); //Result 2147483647
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(int.MinValue)); //Result -2147483648
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(int.MaxValue-int.MinValue)); //Result -1 overflow
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(2147483647-(-2147483648))); //Same as above
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(int.MaxValue+int.MinValue)); //Result -1 no overflow
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(2147483647+(-2147483648))); //Same as above
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(int.MaxValue+1)); //Result -2147483648 overflow
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(2147483647+1)); //Same as above
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(int.MaxValue-int.MaxValue)); //Result 0
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(2147483647-2147483647)); //Same as above
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(int.MaxValue+int.MaxValue)); //Result -2 overflow
Console.WriteLine(unchecked(2147483647+2147483647)); //Same as above
```

The results of these examples should be clear. I'm not doing any casting here to avoid the argument about where the overflow is happening, so it is clear that it is happening in the `int`. Every time an overflow happens, it is as if the first `int` is assigned the value of `int.MinValue` which is -2147483648 and then the second `int` is added/subtracted.

If you cast the first number to `long`, then the result will be `long`. Now no overflow will occur and you will get the same results as in math:

```
Console.WriteLine((long)int.MaxValue); //Result 2147483647
Console.WriteLine((long)int.MinValue); //Result -2147483648
Console.WriteLine((long)int.MaxValue-int.MinValue); //Result 4294967295
Console.WriteLine((long)2147483647-(-2147483648)); //Same as above
Console.WriteLine((long)int.MaxValue+int.MinValue); //Result -1
Console.WriteLine((long)2147483647+(-2147483648)); //Same as above
Console.WriteLine((long)int.MaxValue+1); //Result 2147483648
Console.WriteLine((long)2147483647+1); //Same as above
Console.WriteLine((long)int.MaxValue-int.MaxValue); //Result 0
Console.WriteLine((long)2147483647-2147483647); //Same as above
Console.WriteLine((long)int.MaxValue+int.MaxValue); //Result 4294967294
Console.WriteLine((long)2147483647+2147483647); //Same as above
```

And here is the evidence without using any addition/subtraction. Simply casting a value above the `int.MaxValue` causes an overflow which `unchecked` converts to `int.MinValue`. Any value greater than `int.MaxValue + 1` will be added to `int.MinValue`:

```
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)2147483647)); //Result 2147483647
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)2147483648)); //Result -2147483648 overflow
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)2147483649)); //Result -2147483647 overflow
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)2147483649)); //Result -2147483647 overflow
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)2147483650)); //Result -2147483646 overflow
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)2147483651)); //Result -2147483645 overflow
```

The exact opposite happens when you overflow the `int` with values below `int.MinValue`:

```
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)-2147483648)); //Result -2147483648
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)-2147483649)); //Result 2147483647 overflow
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)-2147483650)); //Result 2147483646 overflow
Console.WriteLine(unchecked((int)-2147483651)); //Result 2147483645 overflow
```

This makes `int` work like an infinite rotating spinner. The two end are glued next to each other, so when you reach one end, you flip to the other one and continue 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3.

Comment: I updated the answer with the values to make it make it clearer. The value of `int.MaxValue` is 2147483647, and the value of `int.MinValue` is -2147483648 (notice that it is negative), so the subtraction result 2147483647 - (-2147483648) is 4294967295, which cannot fit in `int`.

Comment: That depends on the context. When you use the constants values, the complier won't even compile like you said. When you used a function, the compiler will let it go and then it depends on the context. If you're running the code in checked mode, then a runtime overflow exception occurs in the `int` and the `uint` casting is never reached. If you're running the code in unchecked mode, then you are right, you will have two overflows. Check this [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index#arithmetic-overflow) for how the integer overflows behave.